# How do i load fragments out of onClick method in an adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Iv'e been working with fragments so far everything was going well till now. Basically what i want to do is be able load data into a fragment, based on the position from option selected. So far all my attempts have failed.

From what i understand so far ill probably need a communicator interface to help pass that position. Also I don't believe I can access the fragment from the adapter class, it has to be done in the main method.

How do I go about this?

This is my adapter class:

```
public class RouteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RouteAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static List<Routes> routes;
private static List<Routes.stations> stations;
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;
Communicator comm;


public RouteAdapter(List<Routes> routesList) {
    routes = routesList;
    stations = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Routes routes : routesList) {
        stations.addAll(routes.getmStationsList());
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Button BtnRouteName;
    public CardView cardView;
    public TextView TvStationName;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        TvStationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        //cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        final Context context = itemView.getContext();
        BtnRouteName = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.route_name);
        BtnRouteName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Routes s = routes.get(position);
                Routes.stations og = stations.get(position);
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(TvStationName.getText().toString(); //ERROR

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public RouteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.routes_card, parent, false);
    //ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RouteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Routes rPosition = routes.get(position);

    holder.setOnItemClickListener(listener);  //ERROR
    holder.BtnRouteName.setText(rPosition.getmRouteName());
    holder.cardView.setTag(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return routes.size();
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(int position);
}
}
```

This is my main method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Gets the rv from the xml file (activity_main.xml)
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //This is a test fragment just loads a image nothing to really do w/ the problem
    MainActivityFragment frag = new MainActivityFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main_layout, frag, "frag1");
    transaction.commit();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    loadRV();
}

private void loadRV() {
    TrolleyService trolleyService = TrolleyServiceProvider.createService(TrolleyService.class);
    Call<List<Routes>> call = trolleyService.listRoutes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Routes>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Routes>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                mAdapter = new RouteAdapter(response.body());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else {
                Log.d("Oops Something is wrong", response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ERROR", t.getMessage());

        }
    });
}
}
```

one of my Attempts (Requested):
    I deleted most of the codes i tried but something along these lines
        Main Activity:

```
    MainActivityFragment frag = new MainActivityFragment();
    FragmentA fragA = new FragmentA(); //Fragments i wanted to add
    FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB(); //Fragments i wanted to add
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main_layout, frag, "frag1");
    transaction.commit();

     @Override
public void respond(String data) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentB f2 = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.textView);
    f2.changeText(data); //This was a test to display the first name on list
}
```

My Communicator Class

```
public interface Communicator {
public void respond(String data);
```

}

My onClick in Adapter Class

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Routes s = routes.get(position);
        Routes.stations og = stations.get(position);
        comm.respond(og.getStationsName());
    }
```

Comment: `all my attempts have failed` please show single attempt which u have tried.

Comment: Basically, you should make a Listener interface, and pass it as parameter to your adapter. Then you can call something like `mListener.onItemClicked(Object o)`, where your Activity implements `onItemClicked()` and loads the data in the Fragment accordingly

Comment: first confirm with me that button click is working perfect?

Comment: It works outside the adapter for example i can pass the information through the MainActivity only. Attempting to do it from the Adapter is where my problem is. Right now i'm attempting what Benjamin suggested making a Listener interface and going about it like that. I will update this in a second

Answer (score 0):

Place the recyclerView inside a fragment.

I am assuming you are able to get the position of the Adapter. Put recyclerview in a fragment call RV and it's response is to be seen in fragment say RVvalues. You use an interface called PassRVValues

Code in RV fragment:

```
public class RV extends Fragment{
   int RVposition;
   PassRVValues passRVValues;
//
 your code for recyclerview and other things
//
 RVposition = position_value_obtained;
 passRVValues.sendToOtherFragment(RVposition);
```

Here's the code for the interface. Make a new java class having just the interface.

```
public interface PassRVValues{
   sendToOtherFragment(int value_from_RVFragment);
}
```

Code in the activity

```
   public class MainActivity implements PassRVValues{
   //
     some code
   //
   @Override
   public void sendToOtherFragment(int use_value_from_RVFragment){
   //
    Do something with data if you want
   //
   RVvalues Frag = (RVValues)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rvvalues);
   Frag.ShowDataBasedOnPositionInRV(something_based_from_any_process_in_sendToOtherFragment_Method);
   }
```

Now for the code in the RVValues fragment

```
public class RVValues extends Fragment{
    //again any codes//
    public void ShowDataBasedOnPositionInRV(int data_based_on_RV_position){
   //do something//
}
```

This is the way to implement inter-fragment communication in the simplest manner. Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way without using interface

This is your fragment class

```
public class RV extends Fragment{

// your code

}
```

Your Calling Activity

```
public class MainActivity{

// some code

public void setFragment(//params you want to pass){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.ll_container, new RV).commit();
}

}
```

Your Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    public Adapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            button //your button

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     ((MainActivity)context).setFragment(//params you want to pass);
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```